# Azure DevOps: Maven is not installed on agent

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops

I have an Azure Pipeline that is meant to install Java 16 and the run Maven package on my repository. The pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/jdk16'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: AzureStorage
    azureResourceManagerEndpoint: ******
    azureStorageAccountName: ******
    azureContainerName: ******
    azureCommonVirtualFile: jdk-16.0.1_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pom.xml'
    options: '-P test'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: JDKVersion
    mavenVersionOption: Default
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

Unfortunately this does not run correctly and gives me the following error on the Mavern task

> Starting: Maven
> ==============================================================================
> Task         : Maven
> Description  : Build, test, and deploy with Apache Maven
> Version      : 3.186.0
> Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven
> ==============================================================================
> Maven is not installed on the agent
> /usr/bin/mvn -version
> /usr/bin/mvn: 191: exec: /opt/hostedtoolcache/jdk16/JAVA_HOME_16_X64_jdk-16.0.1_linux-aarch64_bin_tar.gz/jdk-16.0.1/bin/java: Exec format error
> ##[error]Build failed.
> ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/home/vsts/agents/2.187.1/externals/node10/bin/node', arguments '"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Maven_ac4ee482-65da-4485-a532-7b085873e532/3.186.0/maventask.js"'.
> Finishing: Maven

However if I remove the first task to install the Java 16 JDK the error I get suggest that Maven is installed as it downloads each of the pom files and errors much later in the process with the error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project printserver: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 16 -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
> [ERROR]
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Which I believe is happening because it cannot access Java 16.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to install the Java 16 JDK and have Maven still play nicely please?

Answer (score 2):

So after much head scratching it turns out the issue was with the JDK version that I was using.

When I swapped from:

jdk-16.0.1_linux-aarch64_bin.tar.gz

to

jdk-16.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

it just started working. Hope this helps someone in the future